# Getting one value of a map in Firestore in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document with this structure in Firestore:

[image: Firestore structure]

Where `queue` is a map. I want to get the value of the key `active` inside

```
val restaurantRef = db.collection("restaurants")
restaurantRef
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                var queueStatus = ArrayList<Boolean>()

                for (document in result) {
                    queueStatus.add( ... ) // How do I get the active value in my map here?
                }
            }
```

How do I get the value of `active` inside my `queue` map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out the answer. On the `queueStatus.add(...)` line, replace it to these lines:

```
val docMap = document.get("queue") as Map<String, *>
queueStatus.add(docMap.get("active") as Boolean)
```